# phpMyadmin error 2002 LEMP Stack

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm using a RedHat Linux Web and DB server. Have PHPMyadmin 4.0.10.2-2 installed on web server w/ PHP 5.3.3 and Nginx 1.4.4. Connecting to the db server, Percona 5.5.32.

I can't log into PHPMyAdmin with mysql credentials anymore. BUT I can log in to mysql via cli and mysql workbench with those credentials.

Modified my /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php to point to the db server which reside on the same subnet. Also specified the root user and other use within this file. Confirmed I could still ping servers and access mysql via web server.
Restarted all services.

Did look in the error logs (/var/log/nginx/phpMyAdmin/error.log) and get this... "2014/09/25 18:36:48 [error] 6457#0: *543 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 67.136.101.122, server: phpmyadmin.domain.com, request: "GET /index.php?token=4086842d92d66bb2f971ef2228c29acf HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "phpmyadmin.domain.com", referrer: "https://phpmyadmin.domain.com/index.php?token=4086842d92d66bb2f971ef2228c29acf"

Things were working just fine yesterday. Did an yum update this morning, which is the last change to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Found the resolution. After many hours, the /etc/phpMyAdmin directory group permission had to be set to nginx.